# How to perform the scroll functionality on mobile emulator with the Kaspresso framework for test automation?

Tags: kotlin, automation, android-espresso

When you try to click on an element which outside of the visible area of the screen, test cases are getting failed. So, you have to scroll to the position before you take any action on the element.

Any sample of how to use this 'AutoScrollProviderImpl' or similar, with the Kaspresso framework?